# How do I transfer a property value from a Table response using Property Transfer in SoapUI?

Tags: soapui

Below is the tabular response of my GetCountry request.

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <soap:Body>
      <GetCitiesByCountryResponse xmlns="http://www.webserviceX.NET">
         <GetCitiesByCountryResult><![CDATA[<NewDataSet>
  <Table>
    <Country>British Indian Ocean Territory</Country>
    <City>Diego Garcia</City>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <Country>India</Country>
    <City>Ahmadabad</City>
  </Table>
  <Table>
</NewDataSet>]]></GetCitiesByCountryResult>
      </GetCitiesByCountryResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

From here I have to copy the values for eg : `Country = India` and `City  = Ahmadabad` to my target request. How can I transfer these values using Property transfer method? Can someone help me with the format?

Comment: Are the country name, city name values fixed?

Comment: Yes, the country and city names are fixed

Answer (score 2):

I think it is not possible with property transfer step.
Try to use below "Script Assertion" which will solve your problem:

Define the following custom properties at your test case level with required country and city names

1. Property Name - `CountryName` and value as `India`
2. Property Name - `CityName` and value as `Ahamadabad`

Add script assertion. How to add script assertion in SOAP UI please refer [Link](https://www.soapui.org/functional-testing/validating-messages/getting-started-with-assertions.html).

```groovy
def searchData = { data, element ->
   def parsedData = new XmlSlurper().parseText(data)
   parsedData.'**'.find {it.name() == element} as String
}

//Closure to check the xpath
def searchByXpath = {data, xpath ->
   def holder = new com.eviware.soapui.support.XmlHolder(data)
   holder.getNodeValue(xpath)
}
assert context.response, "Response is empty or null"
//Gets the CDATA part of the response
def cdata = searchData(context.response, 'GetCitiesByCountryResult')

//Gets the xpath result
def cityName = context.expand('${#TestCaes#CityName}')
def countryName = context.expand('${#TestCaes#CountryName}')
def result = searchByXpath(cdata, "exists(//Table[City = '$cityName' and Country = '$countryName'])")
log.info "Is city ${cityName} and Country ${countryName} exist in the table: ${result}" 
assert result == 'true', "${cityName} and ${countryName} does not exist in the result table"
```

Now to access the above defined properties in next request is to mention as defined below (using Property expansion)

```
<web:CountryName>${#TestCase#CountryName}</web:CountryName>
<web:CityName>${#TestCase#CityName}</web:CityName>
```

Comment: Do you have an idea about whether this can be done using a Groovy Script ??

Comment: Updated the answer with the requested information. Please go thru it and give it a try.